# For single database can i use multiple hibernate configuration file?

Tags: hibernate

1.For single database can i use multiple hibernate configuration file?
    2.DatabaseSession factory is applicable for whole application.Is this possible to create a multiple DatabaseSession factory for single database.

Could anybody clarify my doubt? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

1) For a single project or a DB, multiple hibernate config files can be used. [This](http://www.coderanch.com/t/215378/ORM/databases/hibernate-cfg-xml-project) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3449475/multiple-hibernate-configs) makes it clear.

2) Multiple Session Factories can be created for a single Data source or a single DB. First define the DB details in the applicationContext-database.xml as:

```html
<bean id="dbName_dataSource"
  class="required_dataSource_Type"
  destroy-method="required_type">
  <property name="driverClassName" value="required_driver_name" />    
  <property name="url" value="" />    
  <property name="username" value="" />    
  <property name="password" value="" />       
  <property name="initialSize" value="" />    
  <property name="minIdle" value="" />    
  <property name="maxIdle" value="" />    
  <property name="maxActive" value="" />
  <property name="testOnBorrow" value="" />
  <property name="validationInterval" value=""/>
  <property name="validationQuery" value=""/> 
 </bean>
```

and for the above data source, multiple SessionFactories can be created in the applicationContext-database XML as below:

```html
<bean id="sessionFactory1"
  class="required_SessionFactory_Type">
  <property name="dataSource" ref="dbName_dataSource" />
  <property name="hibernateProperties">
  ...required_additional_details_to_be_provided
 </bean>

<bean id="sessionFactory2"
  class="required_SessionFactory_Type">
  <property name="dataSource" ref="dbName_dataSource" />
  <property name="hibernateProperties">
  ...required_additional_details_to_be_provided 
 </bean>
```

At runtime, the appropriate SessionFactory should be retrieved and it should be used to execute the queries.